# how count the second elements of a nested list where they have the first elements identical?

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list like below:

```
[['A',4],['U',9],['O',9],['A',1],['O',2],['O',1]]
```

How I can count the second elements if they have the same first element?

output:

```
A,5
U,9
O,12
```

without using non-efficient for loops

Comment: What do you mean by "non-efficient for loops"? Are you thinking of an *O(n^2)* solution? Any solution to this will be at least *O(n)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

L = [['A', 4], ['U', 9], ['O', 9], ['A', 1], ['O', 2], ['O', 1]]

c = Counter()
for item, count in L:
    c[item] += count
```

```
>>> c
Counter({'O': 12, 'U': 9, 'A': 5})
```

If insertion order is important, note that `Counter` shows its items in sorted descending order, but if you iterate through it, insertion order is preserved:

```
>>> list(c)
['A', 'U', 'O']
```

Comment: why I get `nan` instead of sum of numbers?

Comment: @user15649753 Sounds like you have some `nan`s in your inputs. The numbers you posted in the question are all integers, so I can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `int` as default. For `int` default value is `0`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [["A", 4], ["U", 9], ["O", 9], ["A", 1], ["O", 2], ["O", 1]]

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in l:
    k, v = i
    d[k] += v
    
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 5, 'U': 9, 'O': 12})

print("\n".join(f"{k},{v}" for k, v in d.items()))
# A,5
# U,9
# O,12
```

Comment: why I get `nan` instead of sum of numbers?

Comment: You could make it a tiny bit cleaner by unpacking earlier: `for k, v in l:`

Comment: @user15649753 do you use numpy (or pandas)?

Answer (score 1):

This should work and with best performance :

```
l = [['A', 4], ['U', 9], ['O', 9], ['A', 1], ['O', 2], ['O', 1]]
d = dict()
for i in l : 
    if not (i[0] in d.keys()) :
        d[i[0]] = i[1]
    else :
        d[i[0]] += i[1]
```